# Does FreeBSD 10.1 have tun/tap kernel modules already integrated?

Tags: module, kernel, freebsd

Does FreeBSD 10.1 have the tun/tap kernel modules already integrated? If yes where are they kept and ow do i load them?
Thanks

Comment: Where you able to check https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt
The link also has references to few examples on using tun and tap devices.  Extract from the link : "This package(http://vtun.sourceforge.net/tun) contains two simple example 
  programs how to use tun and tap devices. Both programs works like 
  bridge between two network interfaces.
  br_select.c - bridge based on select system call.
  br_sigio.c  - bridge based on async io and SIGIO signal.
  However the best example is VTun http://vtun.sourceforge.net :))  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, these drivers are present in GENERIC kernel and you don't need to load anything, see `man tap` and `man tun`. To create tap device you can use `ifconfig create tap`.

Comment: I needed to add the module with kldload if_tap!